# Create expandable listview with group and child checkbox

Tags: java, android, checkbox, treeview, expandablelistview

I want to create an expandable listview with checkboxes present in the groups as well as the children. What I want is, the user may check the group in order to select all the children in the group, or the user may select a particular item under the expandable listview.

This concept is running in our asp.net website as a tree view. I am attaching some screens of the running website:

**Treeview with groups unexpanded**

[image: Treeview with groups unexpanded]

**Treeview with full group selected**

[image: Treeview with full group selected]

**Treeview with particular children selected under group**

[image: Treeview with particular children selected under group]

The **main class**:

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
    ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter;
    ExpandableListView expListView;
    List<String> listDataHeader;
    HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // get the listview
        expListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.lvExp);

        // preparing list data
        prepareListData();

        listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(this, listDataHeader, listDataChild);

        // setting list adapter
        expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

        // Listview Group click listener
        expListView.setOnGroupClickListener(new OnGroupClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                    int groupPosition, long id) {
                // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                // "Group Clicked " + listDataHeader.get(groupPosition),
                // Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return false;
            }
        });

        // Listview Group expanded listener
        expListView.setOnGroupExpandListener(new OnGroupExpandListener() {

            @Override
            public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        listDataHeader.get(groupPosition) + " Expanded",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        // Listview Group collasped listener
        expListView.setOnGroupCollapseListener(new OnGroupCollapseListener() {

            @Override
            public void onGroupCollapse(int groupPosition) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        listDataHeader.get(groupPosition) + " Collapsed",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });

        // Listview on child click listener
        expListView.setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                    int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(
                        getApplicationContext(),
                        listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)
                                + " : "
                                + listDataChild.get(
                                        listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)).get(
                                        childPosition), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    /*
     * Preparing the list data
     */
    private void prepareListData() {
        listDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
        listDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

        // Adding child data
        listDataHeader.add("Top 250");
        listDataHeader.add("Now Showing");
        listDataHeader.add("Coming Soon..");

        // Adding child data
        List<String> top250 = new ArrayList<String>();
        top250.add("The Shawshank Redemption");
        top250.add("The Godfather");
        top250.add("The Godfather: Part II");
        top250.add("Pulp Fiction");
        top250.add("The Good, the Bad and the Ugly");
        top250.add("The Dark Knight");
        top250.add("12 Angry Men");

        List<String> nowShowing = new ArrayList<String>();
        nowShowing.add("The Conjuring");
        nowShowing.add("Despicable Me 2");
        nowShowing.add("Turbo");
        nowShowing.add("Grown Ups 2");
        nowShowing.add("Red 2");
        nowShowing.add("The Wolverine");

        List<String> comingSoon = new ArrayList<String>();
        comingSoon.add("2 Guns");
        comingSoon.add("The Smurfs 2");
        comingSoon.add("The Spectacular Now");
        comingSoon.add("The Canyons");
        comingSoon.add("Europa Report");

        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(0), top250); // Header, Child data
        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(1), nowShowing);
        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(2), comingSoon);
    }
}
```

The **ExpandableListAdapter**:

```
public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    private Context _context;
    private List<String> _listDataHeader; // header titles
    // child data in format of header title, child title
    private HashMap<String, List<String>> _listDataChild;

    public ExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<String> listDataHeader,
            HashMap<String, List<String>> listChildData) {
        this._context = context;
        this._listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
        this._listDataChild = listChildData;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosititon) {
        return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
                .get(childPosititon);
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
            boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
        }

        TextView txtListChild = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.lblListItem);

        txtListChild.setText(childText);
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
                .size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return this._listDataHeader.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
            View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_group, null);
        }

        TextView lblListHeader = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.lblListHeader);
        lblListHeader.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        lblListHeader.setText(headerTitle);

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return true;
    }

}
```

The **activity_main.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#f4f4f4" >

            <ExpandableListView
                android:id="@+id/lvExp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"/>   

</LinearLayout>
```

The **list_group.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="8dp" 
    android:background="#000000">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblListHeader"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredItemPaddingLeft"
        android:textSize="17dp"
        android:textColor="#f9f93d" />
</LinearLayout>
```

The **list_item.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="55dip"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblListItem"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="17dip"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredChildPaddingLeft" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**I have already created a simple expandable listview, now I want to include the checkboxes or any other controls to suffice my requirement.** I have googled for a sutaible tutorial but I was unable to find one. Please help me with one if possible.

Comment: I have included the source code

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To do this you will need to include `boolean` flag in each object, or in you adapter create two list views (for groups and items) that will contain selected items.

I would rather add `boolean` like this :

```
class Group{ ...

  boolean isSelected;
}

class Item { ...

  boolean isSelected;
}
```

Then in `Adapter` in `getViews()` methods:

```
getItemView(...){
  ...
  itemHolder.checkbox.setSelected(item.isSelected)
}

getGroupView(...){
  ...
  groupHolder.checkbox.setSelected(group.isSelected)

  //add lisener
  itemHolder.checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(lisener);
}
```

And on group check you can do something like this :

```
void selectGroup(Group group){
  for(Item item: group.getItems()){
      item.isSelected = true;
  }

  //update your list
  notifiDataSetChanged();
}
```

That's all what you need

**UPDATE** :

- [Android Developers - UI](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/index.html)
- [Android Holder Pattern](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html#ViewHolder)

Comment: I have posted the source code, please check it and tell me where to include your suggestions. Also tell me how to put the checkboxes in the expandable listview groups and children.

Comment: He he - I see you don't know basics. Try to go throw some of articles that I include in post. They will show you how to build your custom design, how to use `Holder` pattern in your adapter and else.

Comment: I did as you instructed, but the groups are not expanding with the checkboxes.

Comment: "or in you adapter create two list views (for groups and items) that will contain selected items."  I tried this initially and got really weird behaviors.  Your boolean method works very well.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Try this sample Code [Expandable CheckList](https://github.com/abhishekdabral/expandchecklist)