# Android: Expandable ListView with parent checkbox and child checkbox

Tags: android, checkbox, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

I want to create a `expandable listview` with `parent checkboxes` and `child checkboxes`. Whenever a `parent checkbox` is selected all the `child checkboxes` should also be selected. Similarly whenever `child checkboxes` are selected/unselected the `parent checkboxes` should behave appropriately.

I have tried with below `Adapter` code after referring to this link 
[Create expandable listview with group and child checkbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22929908/create-expandable-listview-with-group-and-child-checkbox).

```
public class FilterListExpandableListItemAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

private Map<ExpListGroupItem, List<ExpListChildItem>> groupChild;
private List<ExpListGroupItem> groups;
private Activity context;
private ExpandableListView elv;

public FilterListExpandableListItemAdapter(Activity context, List<ExpListGroupItem> cities,
                             Map<ExpListGroupItem, List<ExpListChildItem>> cityArea, ExpandableListView elv) {
    this.context = context;
    this.groupChild = cityArea;
    this.groups = cities;
    this.elv = elv;
}

@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    return groups.size();
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    return groupChild.get(groups.get(groupPosition)).size();
}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
    return groups.get(groupPosition);
}

@Override
public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return groupChild.get(groups.get(groupPosition)).get(childPosition);
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
    return groupPosition;
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return childPosition;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
   ExpListGroupItem group = (ExpListGroupItem) getGroup(groupPosition);
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.filter_drawer_list_parent_item,
                null);
    }
    GroupViewHolder groupHolder = new GroupViewHolder();
    groupHolder.parentCheckBox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.chkbox_filter_drawer_city);
    groupHolder.parentCheckBox.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
    groupHolder.parentCheckBox.setText(group.getGroupName());
    groupHolder.parentCheckBox.setSelected(group.isSelected());
    GroupCheckChangedListener groupCheckChangedListener = new GroupCheckChangedListener();
    groupHolder.parentCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(groupCheckChangedListener);
    convertView.setTag(groupHolder);
    return convertView;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(final int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
                         boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
    final ExpListChildItem child = (ExpListChildItem) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
    LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.filter_drawer_list_child_item, null);
    }
    ChildViewHolder childHolder = new ChildViewHolder();
    childHolder.childCheckBox =(CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.chkbox_filter_drawer_area);
    childHolder.childCheckBox.setSelected(child.isSelected());
    childHolder.childCheckBox.setText(child.getChildName());
    convertView.setTag(childHolder);
    return convertView;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int i, int i1) {
    return true;
}

static class ChildViewHolder {
   CheckBox childCheckBox;
}

static class GroupViewHolder {
    CheckBox parentCheckBox;
}


private class GroupCheckChangedListener implements CheckBox.OnCheckedChangeListener{

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
        ExpListGroupItem group = new ExpListGroupItem();
        CheckBox chk = (CheckBox) compoundButton;
        group.setGroupName(chk.getText().toString());
        for(ExpListChildItem item: groupChild.get(group)){
            item.setIsSelected(true);
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
}}
```

The problem here is I have checked with the `debugger option`. 
My underlying data has changed. But is not reflecting on the `UI`.
Even when I check the parent, corresponding children are not selected.

Can someone please suggest what is it that I am doing wrong here?
Is this the best way to handle the scenario required?

Answer (score 0):

In your getChildView method you should check if parentcheckbox is selected and if yes then

```
childHolder.childCheckBox.setSelected(true);
```

Comment: How to check parentcheckbox is selected or not inside getChildView.