# Parent/Child checkboxes (2 levels of nesting) in Android (Kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to make a static list of checkboxes (not radio buttons) that has 2 levels of nesting:

- Sync All

  - Config

    - Item1
    - Item2
  - Other

I made it to work using switches but I had to create my own logic for handling parent/child.

Then I encountered this:
https://material.io/components/selection-controls/#checkboxes,
where it states that:

> Checkboxes can have a parent-child relationship with other checkboxes.

The way I understood it initially, was that you can basically treat `Checkbox` similar to layout and nest other checkboxes in them (in xml), like here

```
    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="CheckBox"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkBox2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="CheckBox"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/checkBox" />
    </CheckBox>
```

but it doesn't work. I've also looked for some attribute where you could define a parent checkbox but i couldn't find one.

I've also looked here:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CheckBox
and here:
[Create expandable listview with group and child checkbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22929908/create-expandable-listview-with-group-and-child-checkbox)
and based on that, it seems to me that you need to define the parent child logic in the code anyway. Is that correct? What's the most efficient way of doing that, `ViewGroup`?